# Detect negative button press on EditTextPreference

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have a PreferenceActivity with an EditTextPreference. I can easily detect positive button press using `OnPreferenceChangedListener`. However, the listener is never called when the user presses the negative button.

Is there anyway to detect it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot detect it unless you override the `onDialogClosed(...)` in `EditTextPreference` (assuming that you use the old and now deprecated framework version of the preferences):

```java
public class EditTextPreferenceNegative extends EditTextPreference {
    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult); // this will notify the change listener for positive results

        if (!positiveResult) {
            // do something with your negative result
        }
    }
}
```

Note, however, that this will be called even if the dialog is closed without pressing the negative button. If you want to detect only the negative button, you can override the `onClick(...)` method which is called when either of the buttons is clicked.

Comment: Maybe it's offtopic but if I want to switch to Androidx via the inbuilt migration option in Android studio, will this code break? And also how to use this class? Is it like `(myEditTextPref as EditTextPreferenceNegative)`?

Comment: You have to use this class in your XML file. If this class is located in the package "com.something.cool", then in your preferences XML you'd write `<com.something.cool.EditTextPreferenceNegative ... />`. Upgrading to the AndroidX version is not trivial in this case as this specific logic was moved to a separate class (`EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat`) that handles only the dialog. It'd require more work, but you'll have to do it eventually as the framework preference classes are deprecated.